# switch statement in listBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

How can I use **switch** statement in my case, if I'm using **listBox**?

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox2.GetSelected(0))
                richTextBox1.Text = "0";
            else if (listBox2.GetSelected(1))
                richTextBox1.Text = "1";

        }
```

Comment: Use the [ListBox.SelectedItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `GetSelected`. If you want just to save the index, you don't even need the `switch/case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
switch (listBox2.FindString(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()))//find the index of the selected string
{
    case 0:
        richTextBox1.Text = "0";
        break;
    ...
}
```

Although, it would be more effective then to just call

```
//Do the same as above, then convert to string
richTextBox1.Text = listBox2.FindString(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToString();
```

As this gets the selected item, finds its index, then convert the index to a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (listBox2.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        richTextBox1.Text = "0";
        break;
    case 1:
        richTextBox1.Text = "1";
        break;
}
```

Or:

```
richTextBox1.Text = listBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```